# Swinject always return nil when trying to resolve any object

Tags: swift, swiftui, dependency-injection, property-wrapper, swinject

I have the following Swinject implementation in my app -

```swift
import Foundation
import Swinject

@propertyWrapper
struct Inject<Component> {
    let wrappedValue: Component
    init() {
        self.wrappedValue = Resolver.shared.resolve(Component.self)
    }
}

class Resolver {
    static let shared = Resolver()
    private var container = buildContainer()
    
    func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
        container.resolve(T.self)!
    }
}

func buildContainer() -> Container {
     
    let container = Container()
    container.register(BasicApplicationNetworkService.self) { _ in
        return BasicApplicationNetworkService()
    }.inObjectScope(.container)
    
    container.register(BasicApplicationViewModel.self) { resolver in
        return BasicApplicationViewModel()
    }.inObjectScope(.container)
    
    container.register(BasicApplicationView.self) { resolver in
        return BasicApplicationView()
    }.inObjectScope(.container)
    
    return container
    
}

@main
struct BasicApplicationApp: App {
        
    @Inject
    var statingView : BasicApplicationView
    
    var body: some Scene {

        WindowGroup {
            statingView
        }
    }
}
```

I always get a `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on my App struct when initialising.

Can't figure out what I am missing - I have a singleton object that should be initialized on runtime. Something in the Resolver class seems missing, but when debugging this code it does indeed go through the `buildContainer()` method and intializes what it's supposed to initialise - but still nil is being returned. Seems like something really obvious but it's 0:44 AM so hopefully someone is more awake then I am...

Comment: Try to remove `.inObjectScope(.container)` for view, View is a value type.

Comment: @Asperi just tried, did not work. still nil

Comment: @Asperi weirdly enough, I always get the nil on the ViewModel but not on anything else. Any suggestions why?